# Dev dependency in dotnet core?

Tags: .net, .net-core

We have 2 projects in the same solution. A `client` and a `server`. The build of the `server` generates a swagger.json. The build of the `client` uses that swagger.json to generate a rest client. It is important that the build of the `server` runs before the build of the `client`, however we don't want to add a `<ProjectReference>`, as there is no runtime dependency.

Is it possible to add a build-time dependency between both projects? We can set the build order in the `.sln` file, but that one isn't used with `dotnet build`. The build server also ignores the `.sln` file entirely.

This is simular to a `devDependency` in nodejs, or a dependency with `provided` scope in maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `dotnet msbuild <solution_file.sln>`, this way the solution file shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: I guess that works. But it's not a very clean solution if you ask me. Its too bad that there is no way to create a build dependency.